# Family Reunion - Germany

Tags: germany, blue-card, family

wanted to ask a few questions about family reunion visas. Some context - My partner came to Germany in Oct 2022 for work. She procured an EU Blue Card for this. I also procured an EU Blue Card to come to Germany for work, as my job sponsored me to do so through a payroll company. A few days after I landed in Germany, she lost her job due to the tech layoffs. We had already been planning to elope in Denmark this year and thought that now given her job loss it would be a good time to get it sorted so that she would have the option to get a family reunion visa as my dependent. Not sure if it's relevant but I am an Indian citizen and she is a US citizen. We've had a few conflicting pieces of info about how it might go from here and would love anyone's insight on this:

1. We were told that we have to wait 2 years before she can apply for a family reunion visa because we would be getting married after I got my visa for Germany. Is this correct?
2. Can she work for a non-Germany based company on a family reunion visa? We were told yes in some places and no in others. Some have told us that she can but the company would need to hire a payroll company for her to be able to do that so she has a German contract.
3. Would she have to prove an A1 level of German to apply for the family reunion even though I have a BC?

Any other anecdotes from anyone's experiences would be much appreciated!

Comment: Nobody reads such long questions on a website where new users like you hardly upvote answers (think what incentive do people have who answer?)

Comment: I'm new because I didn't know about this forum - I'm just hoping that someone knows something. If not, no worries. I'll figure out another way. Thanks! @quantum